# How to pass NAN value?

Tags: pandas, nan

Simply, Are there any ways to ignore NAN values rather than replacing other value or deleting?

I imported an excel file as a dataframe which have Nan values in the column.
This column contains IP addresses so it looks like below

```py
 IP address
10.10.10.10
20.20.20.20
blank(NAN)
30.30.30.30
blank(NAN)
```

When I use `socket.getfqdn()` to know hostname of IP address but when it facing the NAN value, there is an error message, AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'strip'.

I wanted to do like below.

```py
if data.iloc[a, 0] = NAN
    a+=1
```

Are there any ways to do like this?
I attached my code so far, just in case

```
import pandas as pd
import socket

a = 0

data = pd.read_excel("ipaddress.xlsx")
last_raw_no = len(data) - 1
print('\n excel file reading is done')

while True:

    hostname = socket.getfqdn(data.iloc[a, 0])
    data.loc[a, 'Dst Name'] = hostname
    print(data.iloc[a, 0], '---', data.iloc[a, 1])

    if a == last_raw_no :
        break

    else :
        a+=1
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [`math.isnan()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isnan)

> Return True if x is a NaN (not a number), and False otherwise.

```py
import math
if math.isnan(data.iloc[a, 0]):
    a += 1
```

You may also want to check the type of value before

```py
from numbers import Real
import math
if isinstance(data.iloc[a, 0], Real) and math.isnan(data.iloc[a, 0]):
    a += 1
```

---

### [`pd.isna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.isna.html)

Since you are using pandas already, `pd.isna()` could be a better choice

```py
if pd.isna(data.iloc[a, 0]):
    a += 1
```

Comment: It worked!! I use pd.isna(), another problem comes up though :(, Thank you so much :)